# Edit Text not allowing to enter value when the value entered is within the range

Tags: android

Below is the code which i use in my edit text to take value only within a certain range

```
 EditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(Min, Max)});
```

this is my fuction:

```
 public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        int input = 0;
        try {
            input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

This code works when min is 1 and max is 10, but it is not working when min is 20 and max is 30
please help,thanks in advance

Comment: Use `TextWatcher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        int input = 0;
        try {
            **if(end==1){
               min = Integer.parseInt(source.toString());
            }**
            input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Appending `if (end==1) { min = Integer.parseInt(source.toString()); }` works fine for me.

However, a better approach for what you are trying to implement is to use TextWatcher as mentioned by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057891/3762879)

Comment: When i set min = 20 and max = 25 then it should not allowed 5 as input in edittext.

Comment: As mentioned, it is recommended to use TextWatcher to handle this case. filter will only restrict user to enter a value while using TextWatcher, we can validate if the value lies in the allowed limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you start typing '20', the first number is 2, and 2 is not between 20 and 30.

I suggest you to use TextWatcher instead :

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if(s.length() > 0) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (num >= Min && num <= Max)
            {
                // Place your logic here. EG : save the number.
            }
            else{
                // Your are not in the desired range. 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

EditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```